# What Would Cause My Shimano Front Disc Brake to Leak after Replacement?

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake

I noticed my Shimano BT M400 front brake caliper was missing the cap for the bleed nipple and the whole set up was covered in mineral oil.

After speaking briefly to a mechanic I bought a replacement caliper and today got round to swapping in the new caliper.

I took the opportunity to swap from EU to UK brake set up so the new caliper would've been put on a different lever to the previous one.  As with the last time I set up, everything seemed fine; but then just a few minutes into riding home I looked at the front wheel and the dust cap was half off - being pushed out by leaking mineral oil - and all brake pressure was gone.

So that's the same leak on two different calipers and using two different levers. Does anyone have any suggestions what might be the issue?

Logically I'm guessing it's a cable issue?

Comment: Unless you have a cable-actuated, remote master cylinder hydraulic system, which are pretty unique/rare, there are no cables in a hydraulic brake system.

Comment: It sounds like you are not sealing off the bleed nipple properly. The leak could conceivably be from the hose joint at the caliper too. Did you use a new olive etc?

Comment: Diagnosis questions preceding an answer: are you sure you're installing the caliper correctly? I'm guessing you reused both existing hoses? New olive and barb? MT400 has plastic pistons so cracks shouldn't be an issue (unlike with fancy ceramic pistons).